# Can't access health check

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, google-app-engine

I am currently working on a web app using Django. I used this app.yaml and it is deployed successfully on google app engine. However, I couldn't access /_hc, because Django checks whether the url is in url patterns and it just responds with 'Page not found'. How do I fix this?

```
runtime: python37
entrypoint: bash -c 'gunicorn -b :$PORT projectservice.wsgi'
liveness_check:
  path: "/_hc"
  check_interval_sec: 30
  timeout_sec: 4
  failure_threshold: 2
  success_threshold: 2
handlers:
# This configures Google App Engine to serve the files in the app's
# static directory.
- url: /static
  static_dir: static/
# This handler routes all requests not caught above to the main app. 
# It is required when static routes are defined, but can be omitted 
# (along with the entire handlers section) when there are no static 
# files defined.
- url: /.*
  script: auto
# [END django_app]
```

Comment: maybe use this: https://pypi.org/project/django-health-check/ and add /_hc as the url of the health check. this package have different modes to health check database, cache and etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fine, but you need to have a url handler for `/_hc` that returns a `200` response:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def health_check_handler(request):
    return HttpResponse("healthy", content_type='text/plain')
```

in urls.py:

```
(r'^_hc$', 'health_check_handler'),
```

Comment: Wouldn't this always give a 200 response?

Comment: If the app can run, yes.  Per docs: "Liveness checks confirm that the VM and the Docker container are running. Instances that are deemed unhealthy are restarted."